# Autocomplete with Categories and remote datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What I want to do is have categorised results using autocomplete through jQueryUI's function. After some googling etc I found that it has an inbuilt function (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories) but the example is only for a local data source (an array in javascript). I am dealing with a remote data source. The autocomplete side of it works fine without the categories code added in but breaks when it is added.

This means that the php code is fine (the search page that returns json data).

I took this code from the jQueryUI site:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
                    var self = this,
                    currentCategory = "";
                $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                    currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
```

I then combined it with the search side of it (changing to category):

```
$(function() {
        $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
            delay:0,
            source: "query/encode-json.php?term="+ $("#search").val(),
            select: function(event, ui){
                alert(ui.item.label);
            }
        });     
    });
```

But it does not work :( I've googled a lot but everyone else was having issues with the json side of it. Here's my json data:

```
[{"value":"some dude","id":"1","category":"artist"},{"value":"some other dude","id":"2","category":"artist"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is the `source` property of the options object you're passing to autocomplete:

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    delay:0,
    source: "query/encode-json.php?term="+ $("#search").val(),
    select: function(event, ui){
        alert(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

`source` will be evaluated *once* when you instantiate the widget. In other words, `$("#search").val()` does not get executed every time the user types.

Since by default autocomplete sends up `term` in the query string, you should just be able to do:

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    delay:0,
    source: "query/encode-json.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
        alert(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure everything else is correct, since using your array as a local data source with categories works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jadPP/

Comment: Thanks for trying. Still doesn't work. The reason that I added in what I added (  ?term="+ $("#search").val(),  ) was that the value that is entered needs to be passed to the php script that attempts to find similar values. It does narrow down the results currently as you type more and more (ignoring categories).

Comment: And you said it works without categories? That is strange... If you open up Firebug do the requests look correct? Do you have a publicly accessible site I could take a look at by any chance?

Comment: Here we go: http://coverartists.net/artist-search.php To explain it. The search at the top right uses the (attempted) categories code. The bigger search uses the pre-existing code etc (and works). So, you'll see how the added value bit does work etc. Thanks :)

Comment: And start type sam or st. EDIT: There are some css issues in firefox. I know. Haven't bothered looking at them yet.

Comment: Looks like there are some issues with the order of your scripts--I am getting a JS error on the `$(window).load` code. Make sure you load jQuery first before the other scripts. When I type in the textbox in question I don't see any AJAX requests going up

Comment: See, the weird thing is that the bottom search box still functions fine, so I can't see how that would affect it. (Though I just got rid of some old javascript code for a no-longer used plugin).

Comment: Got it working :) Turned out at some point I'd deleted some of the end points of the widget section so just recopied it from the jQueryUI website and it worked. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

*(Updated)*

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. I need categories like in the jqueryui link that work with a php query. My php query is working, along with the json data (including category information being passed) but I can't get the category side of it to display.

Answer (score 0):

The default `_renderItem()` method looks for `item.label`, but your json data contains `item.value`. You need to change your encode-json.php script to use `label` instead of `value`, or you'll have to use the version of `source:` where you provide your own callback function.

Comment: Attempted that but didn't work. Swapped value with label. Thanks though

Comment: This simply isn't true. Autocomplete items get normalized into a consistent format long before `_renderItem` is called.

Comment: I think that normalization only happens if you use one of the compact forms of source: that returns an array of strings. If your AJAX call returns objects, how is the normalization supposed to know which attribute in the objects should be used? The normal way this is done is by using a callback function that extracts the completion data, but he's not doing that.

Comment: Changed back to value and it still works. So... yah :) Just happy that it works I guess :)